# How to force a command in GRAFCET?

Tags: parallel-processing, plc

I'm trying to force a command in my `grafcet` using `Fluid SIM`.

1. If state no. 80 is currently active only `G90` partial grafcet should run
2. If state no. 81 is currently active only `G90` partial grafcet should run

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.mhj-wiki.de/en/grafcet-workbook/grafcet-workbook-12/). The problem is that I can't block my `partial grafcets`. I don't know why, but **the problem in** my case is that they both execute in parallel even though the `G82` grafcet should be blocked on `INIT` by state no. 80.

[image: G]

Answer (score -1):

> **CLAIM** : *"the problem…is that they **both execute in parallel**…though the G82 grafcet should be blocked on `INIT` by state no. 80."*

The claim is principally false.

They may, upon `T1`-condition was met, happen to start executing **`G90{state:INIT}`** , **some nonzero time *after* `G82{state:90}` was started**, so just co-incidentally appearing to concurrently do something in the environment. Definitely not a **True-`[PARALLEL]`**-execution and expect no explicit blocking from the top-left FSA (unless some indeed nasty tricks were hidden inside FSA-state-transition variables effectively causing a mutual-(dead)-block for the otherwise just time-constrained (if present) Finite-State-Automata having conditional-variables in control of the ***pure-*`SEQUENCE`** of the designed state-transitions.

The Grafcet "front-end" for a PLC-programming ( masking the principal properties of `SEQUENTIAL`, weakly-coordinated at maximum, Finite-State-Automata ) has some principles, that must get reflected in the easy-to-sketch (yet, complicated)-FSA design-rules. One of which is **"How to block, alike MUTEX"** :

> <sub>*If several transitions are to follow a step, then an alternative branch is used. As the name implies, alternative sequences can be realised with this. Only one process is ever performed, however. For this reason, the transition conditions for the transitions that branch into the individual sequences need to be **mutually exclusive**. The individual sequences of an alternative branch are also called partial sequences.
> ...
> ...**the programmer must define** each of the following transition conditions **so that only one condition can be fulfilled.** The transition conditions therefore must be mutually exclusive.*</sub> **If this is not the case, then the behaviour remains undefined**<sub>, i.e. no prediction can be made as to which partial sequence will be performed. In Grafcet-Studio, the partial sequence whose transition first initiates the transition would be performed.</sub>
>   [image]

---

### How to make the autonomous FSA-s to run at least *somewhat* in **`[PARALLEL]`**?

Kindly notice both of the "blocking" BARRIERS, and rigorously put, expect no explicit timing-coordination / state-transition conditional-variables' caused mutual-deadlocks checks / collision avoidance inside the just co-*"parallel"* FSA-control **`[SEQUENCE]`**-s :

> <sub>*A **parallel sequence** is used when several partial sequences are to be started simultaneously after a transition. The first steps in the partial sequences are activated simultaneously by a transition here. The partial sequences are thus started synchronously, which is the reason why the symbol for a parallel branch is also referred to as a synchronisation symbol. The partial sequences then remain independent from one another, i.e. they run in parallel. At the end, the partial sequences flow back to a synchronisation symbol and a subsequent transition. This transition is only released once all the partial sequences have been processed in full. Therefore, the partial sequences are also synchronised at the end.*</sub>
>   [image]

---

### RESUMÉ :

[image]
The top-left FSA introduces a mandatory,
self-repeating
flow of **`SEQUENCE`** of steps :
**first**
forcing **`SEQ_G82`**-`(jump_into_state:82)`,
**next**, only after this and based on meeting the FSA-state-transition *"variable"* **`T1`** condition,
forcing **`SEQ_G80`**-`(jump_into_state:INIT)`
**next**
loop-to-*"first"*

Comment: Actually the problem is that one of them should be stuck (as I understand from the theory) and the other one should run. I was trying to understand how to use `force command`.

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu Forcing is obviously an independent tool to trigger some other, "external" ( out-of-order ) FSA-sequence ( + move it right into an explicitly requested ( addressed by enumerated states ) state ), yet any such sequence of such independent "external" FSA-s forced to start does not "interact", the less block or manifest some other, wished to have behaviour. Forcing is possible, yet all the conditions are up to the code-designer ( the tool explicitly rejects to bear any responsibility for automated checks or deadlock avoidance et al )

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong. If I `force command` a block from a `partial grafcet` to `INIT`, shouldn't it stay on the `INIT` block until the "main" sequence release the `force command`?

Comment: @CătălinaSîrbu That happens not before **T1**-released the main loop to step out of **[80]**, next the state-**[81]** introduces a forced-command **in-state-[81]=DO=G90{ INIT }** be executed ( now, being "blocked" there, inside the state-**[81]**, nevertheless no longer, than the **T2**-releases the "main"-FSA to step "out-of" the state-**[81]**, as moving forwards, into the state-**[80]=DO=G82{ state-[82] }** again and the partial-GRAFCET **[G90]** may get and gets after **1s / X90** from the { initial }-state-**[90]** next step into a state-**[91]** .. *which is depicted in the green-colour*